# Controlling image height in Bootstrap-Lightbox gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website of an artist, so galleries are really important. I'm using Bootstrap for the website, and Lightbox for Bootstrap plugin for the galleries. It works fine adjusting the width of the image to any resolution (I want to make it as responsive as possible). But, as you can observe if you click on any vertical photo (for example, the one in the second row, second column), when it opens, it's bigger than the screen and it can't be seen without scrolling.

So, I want to get rid of this problem, adjusting the maximum height of the image to the height of the screen. But I can't find the way to do this. Any ideas for doing it in a simple way? I've uploaded the website to a server so you can see the problem: http://mural.uv.es/ivape2/es/galeria.html

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a tough time with this.  It's almost that you have to make the modal itself vertically responsive... it's just how to accomplish that at this point?  By default, BS modals will overflow vertically and that's what's happening here.  I'll keep trying.  Even though the "img-responsive" class is being called, the modal itself is not getting any smaller.

Comment: 4 answers. None of them accepted?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and [tinny77's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28829494/266531) was the only thing that approached a solution.

Here is a working snippet of what I ended up with

```js
 $().ready(function() {
   $('[data-toggle="lightbox"]').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).ekkoLightbox({
       type: 'image',
       onContentLoaded: function() {
         var container = $('.ekko-lightbox-container');
         var image = container.find('img');
         var windowHeight = $(window).height();
         if(image.height() + 200 > windowHeight) {
           image.css('height', windowHeight - 150);
           var dialog = container.parents('.modal-dialog');
           var padding = parseInt(dialog.find('.modal-body').css('padding'));
           dialog.css('max-width', image.width() + padding * 2 + 2);
         }
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/3.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click Image</p>
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/400/1920" data-toggle="lightbox">
    <img height="200" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/1920"/>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To tweak navigation arrows to match the height dynamically, add the below code after overriding the CSS, "dialog.css() code".
dialog.find('.glyphicon').css('line-height', (windowHeight - 100)+"px");

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way by editing the Javascript:

```
onContentLoaded: function() {
          var imgh = $(".ekko-lightbox-container").find("img").height();
          var winh = $(window).height();
          if ((imgh+200)>winh)
          {
            $(".ekko-lightbox-container").find("img").css("height",winh-150).css("width","auto").css("margin","0 auto");
          }
        }
```

Comment: Snippet doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johncusak18/9ka1y8rq/)

```
.container {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;   
}
.item {
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Assuming you have a `.container` width a given width/height. I've put both width and height at 100% for the `.container`

Then you just create a class and asign it `max-width: 80%;` which will output the image to be 80% the width of the `.container`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
.ekko-lightbox.modal.fade.in div.modal-dialog{
  max-width:27%;
}
```

This is just simple solution, best it will be to make media-queries for different resolution

Comment: I see, more or less, what do you mean, but I can't get it to work. I think the problem is that, whatever css I put in order to resize the objects, is overwritten by the javascript which opens the image. So, I think, I should have to change the javascript code that opens the image, but it's too complicated for me. Can you help me with this, or should I find another gallery? In that case, there is any gallery, compatible with Bootstrap (Modal) that is horizontal and vertical responsive? Although I'd prefer to mantain Bootstrap-Lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

This has been [solved](https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox/issues/92) ([commit on github](https://github.com/manveru/lightbox/commit/fb12fd8c6321d3f189eef7c28e67b936959c8ff4)) by calculating the maximum image height (80% of viewport height) in the preload function but currently it is not part of the base branch.